# How can I transfer data from a SQL table to an Oracle table?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have a `_Users_` table in MS SQL Server, then I created the same table in Oracle. How I can retrieve data from SQL table to my new Oracle table? Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "table in sql" ? MS SQL Server, MySQL ?

Comment: Is the table big or complex? If not, CSV export/import would probably be the easiest.

Comment: Create a database link & `insert into oracle_table ( select * from users@dblink)`

Comment: Table is in MS SQL Server having more than 600 rows, not more complex.

Answer (score 1):

See this blog post, there is discussed how to use heterogeneous services and example of how to retrieve data in oracle from sql server:

http://geogeeks.net/2011/01/28/oracle-heterogeneous-serviceshsodbc/

Query data from sql server and insert into oracle table via database link... First of all see the above blog.

Answer (score 0):

What version or Oracle? Is it MS SQL Server or My Sql?
You can take a look at [Hetrogenous Services](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a76960/hs_admin.htm#15089) which involves:

- Install ODBC
- Setup tnsnames.ora for odbc connectivity (authentication=none)
- Create db-link

Also, this is a useful [link](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_heterogeneous_database_connections_sql_server.htm) regarding this topics.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple migration tools are available which are specifically made for migrating data from database to database. In your case i would suggest Keeptool. It has import and export facility to transfer/migrate data.
Here is a link to keeptool
http://www.keeptool.com/index_en.php